# Powershell 7zip compress and delete

Tags: file, powershell, archive, 7zip

Ok so I'm still learning so please treat me like an idiot. 
I have put together a script from various sources that will grab all files with given extension and age in a folder and use 7zip to compress the files. 
What i also want to add is a way for the files that are successfully compressed to be deleted. 
Now 7zip returns a message: "Everything is ok" after each file so i would guess there would be some way to take that and mark that file for deletion.

My current code for compressing is below any help or tips on the deleting process would be awesome.
Lucas

```
<#  
This script compresses all files with given extension in the set folder
and add to daily archive ".zip" using 7izp.
#>


#### 7 zip variable I got it from the below link 
#### http://www.7-zip.org/ 
# Alias for 7-zip
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw         "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
  set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

############################################
#### Variables 

# The location of the files you want to compress
$filePath = "D:\temp"

# select extension, use .* for all
$e = ".pdf"

# Select in days how old a file must be to be processed.
$d = 10

#get the files in the folder the match requirements
$ed = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object { _.Extension -eq "$e" -and $_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$d) }

#Gets current date for creating daily archive
$date1 = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

#Gets current dir for using in archive folder name
$path = Split-Path $filepath -Leaf


###########################################
############Function

foreach ($file in $ed) {
                $name = $file.name
                $directory = $file.DirectoryName
                $zipfile = "$path-$date1.zip"
                sz a -tzip "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"     
            }

########### END OF SCRIPT ##########
```

Comment: So... has `Remove-Item` not helped out?

Comment: I think it would, but the issue i am having is i want to make sure the file get's zipped before it gets deleted and that it is not deleted if the zip process fails.

Comment: You could call 7zip with `Start-Process` and `-Wait`. then if its still inefficient you could use jobs

Comment: Thanks, i shall have a look.